# Get all inputs, selects and buttons and their order number in form using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please see this code:

```
<form id=form1>
    <input name="TextBox1" type="text" value="1111111111" id="TextBox1" />
    <input name="TextBox2" type="text" value="222222222" id="TextBox2" />
    <select name="DropDownList1" id="DropDownList1">
       <option value="1">1</option>
       <option value="2">2</option>
       <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    <input id="CheckBox1" type="checkbox" name="CheckBox1" />
    <label for="CheckBox1">nima</label>
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" />
</form>
```

I want to get all control element in form using jquery with order number.For example:

```
ElementID       order number
--------------------------------
TextBox1              1
TextBox2              2
DropDownList1         3
CheckBox1             4
Button1               5
```

How I can do this?
thanks

Comment: BTW: That's _order_ number rather than _hierarchy_ number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not hierarchy number, it is index.

```
$.each($('#form1').find('input, select'), function()
{
    alert('Index: ' + $(this).index());
});
```

Or, if you need consecutive numbers

```
$.each($('#form1').find('input, select'), function(counter)
{
    alert('Index: ' + counter);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [:input](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) and [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) for order number:

```
$('#form1 :input').each(function(index)
{
    console.log(this.id + " " + (index + 1));
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k9eLrv5h/)

Answer (score 1):

You can get all children elements of the form by doing `$('#form1').children()` which will return only immediate children of the form (i.e. no `<option>` tags from inside `<select>`).

You can then call .index() on each element to get its order within the form http://api.jquery.com/index/